# What's the basic story in the series of Mega Man X?

Tags: mega-man-x

As a kid, I loved playing Mega Man X for the mechanics and didn't really pay attention to the story. I have been playing [20XX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20XX_(video_game)), and am realizing that I am unable to make any connections to the analog characters besides Nina (Mega Man) and Ace (Zero). I have vague memories of a collection of scientists, and specifically a "Dr. Light". I would like to have a basic grasp on the story and characters of the X series without having to play through the games again. Can someone provide a summary?

Comment: i don't get where *20XX* fits in to all of this. it's inspired by *Megaman X* but it's got nothing to do with it

Comment: @Memor-X I was just sharing what piqued my interest. You can disregard that part if you want. My question is about the X series.

Comment: @Frank This question is explicitly On-topic according to bullet point #4: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, this is on-topic as far as I know, but Frank's point is that it shows low research effort, which is a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: My main argument is asking us to summarize the entire story is too broad.  There are eight games, at least.  This is literally what a wiki is for, not Arqade.

Comment: I agree with Frank here. If you had a specific question about the story, that would be acceptable. Asking to summarize the entire game's story is too broad and should be researched elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 versions of the story because of the original *Megaman X* game and *Megaman Maverick Hunter X* which came with the *The Day of Σ* OVA which served as a prequel. However there is a common theme to it.

---

Basically Sigma was a Commander for Maverick Hunter created by Dr Cain. Well before the events of Megaman X/Maverick Hunter X (how in [*Megaman X4*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlpXQ2WQtrQ)) he was dispatched to deal with a "Red Maverick" (later to be revealed as Zero). During the fight that took place near Zero's capsule both Zero (who was suffering from a flaw in his programming) and Sigma were infected by The Maverick Virus (which it's thought that Dr Wily had some hand in creating given that he created Zero).

The Maverick Virus fixed Zero's flawed programming but it mutated in Sigma, fusing with his mind and becoming The Sigma Virus. The Virus allowed Sigma to manipulate and control Reploids and he began to believe that humanity was keeping the potential of Reploid down, especially given that Reploids were based off X who Dr Cain discovered 100 years after the Megaman series (long after the death of Dr Light) however was not able to replicate perfectly.

To Sigma this meant Reploids were based off X but were made to be inferior compared to him on purpose, more so when he was Dr Cain's masterpiece and the finest of the Reploids yet was still almost defeated by Zero when they first encountered one another.

After this we enter into *Megaman X*, Sigma's First rebellion, where Sigma used his abilities to control his former subordinates in Maverick Hunter (the bosses you face) and making them see his point of view.

---

In *The Day of Σ* it shows X's and Zero's interactions with the their future Maverick foes such as Storm Eagle, Chill Penguin and Vile. in it however after being discovered by the duo Sigma launched the entire payload from the Missile Base he was and aimed them at Able City after being discovered by X.

While still somewhat compatible with the original story line the missile attack deviates from the original back story as

> Dr Cain, who was wheelchair bound and living off life support, was killed in the missile attack. This remained constant in *Maverick Hunter X* where X's adviser is an unnamed Female, Mass-Produced Reploid Navigator at Maverick Hunter (not Alia), while in the games (X1-3 at least) Dr Cain advises X and Zero.

*The Day of Σ* also shows that the scarring of Sigma's eyes was caused by X after the missile attack. However, in *Megaman X4* it's shown that it might have been Zero who scarred him as the skin Sigma loses on his right side looks very much like the purple scars he has in the series.

---

Beyond that the story of the game is much the same. X and Zero track down their former comrades while information is gathered as to where Sigma was located.

While in the original game Vile was just shown as being a loyal bodyguard to Sigma, in *Maverick Hunter X* and its unlockable Vile Mode, Vile is shwon to have been jealous of X and didn't join Sigma's rebellion, instead wanting to prove that he was better than X for Sigma's plans.